# How to extend KeyValuePair stuct operators in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, operator-overloading, keyvaluepair

Let say I have two KeyValuePair variable.

```
     KeyValuePair<string, double> kv1 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("a", 5);
     KeyValuePair<string, double> kv2 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("b", 7);
```

There is no definition of + operation in "KeyValuePair" struct.
So I want to use operator overloading!

My target is to get third KeyValuePair type variable like:

```
  KeyValuePair<string, double> kv1 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>(kv1.Key + " + " + kv2.Key, kv1.Value + kv2.Value);
```

And the result will be :

```
KeyValuePair<string, double>("a + b", 12)
```

But tell me how to do it using "operator" ?

I was trying to do it like this way:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    public Form1()
    {
     KeyValuePair<string, double> kv1 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("a", 5);
     KeyValuePair<string, double> kv2 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("b", 7);

     KeyValuePair<string, double> k = kv1 + kv2;
    }
    public static KeyValuePair<string, double> operator +(KeyValuePair<string, double> c1, KeyValuePair<string, double> c2) => new KeyValuePair<string, double>(c1.Key + " + " + c2.Key, c1.Value + c2.Value);
}
```

But there is an error message that: 
"At least one of the parameters should be Form1"

Which means that you can only create operator for Form.From1 inputs...
I thought to extend KeyValuePair class!
But then I introduced that "KeyValuePair" is a struct but it is not a class!

Can we create new struct which inherits from "KeyValuePair" struct?

So How to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd expect `"a" + "b"` to produce `"ab"`, not `"a + b"`... Either way, if you want operator overloading you'll have to create your own type. If you want both operator overloading and need to use `KeyValuePair`, you can define (explicit and/or implicit) [conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) to ease conversion between your own type and `KeyValuePair`.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do this.

There is no way to add operators to other types, you *must* add them *inside* the types involved.

The best you can do is either to create an extension method or just a normal method somewhere.

However, extension method isn't easy either since you don't have access to operators for generic types in generic methods.

Extension method example that doesn't work:

```
public static class MyKeyValuePairExtensions
{
    public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Add<TKey, TValue>(
        this KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> first,
        KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> second)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(
            first.Key + second.Key,
            first.Value + second.Value);
    }
}
```

This will fail to compile with this:

> CS0019 Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TKey' and 'TKey'

Now, you *could* add in various 3rd party nuget packages that lets you simulate this but I'm going to leave this as an excercise for the reader.

A different alternative would be to just add an extension method for your specific case:

```
public static class MyKeyValuePairExtensions
{
    public static KeyValuePair<string, double> Add(
        this KeyValuePair<string, double> first,
        KeyValuePair<string, double> second)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, double>(
            first.Key + " + " + second.Key,
            first.Value + second.Value);
    }
}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
KeyValuePair<string, double> kv1 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("a", 5);
KeyValuePair<string, double> kv2 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("b", 7);
var sum = kv1.Add(kv2); Key="a + b", and Value=12
```

[Here's a .NET Fiddle to experiment with](https://dotnetfiddle.net/95I7PQ).